# SQL Server JOIN returns no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have this situation in my database:

```
SELECT A.No_ as itemno,A.Description as description from
[dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item] A
WHERE (A.No_ LIKE  '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI 
or A.Description LIKE '%020212601%' COLLATE  Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI);
```

returns only one row

```
+-----------+-------------+
|  itemno   | description |
+-----------+-------------+
| 020212601 | BLA BLA     |
+-----------+-------------+
```

My second table returns this:

```
select * from [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference] B 
where B.[Item No_] LIKE  '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI ;

+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+--+
| Item No_  | Cross-Reference Type | Cross-Reference No_ |  |
+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+--+
| 020212601 |                    2 |                     |  |
| 020212601 |                    2 |           020212601 |  |
| 020212601 |                    2 |                     |  |
| 020212601 |                    2 |           020212601 |  |
+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+--+
```

Now I join with both tables:

```
select A.No_ as itemno,A.Description as description, A.[Producto M3] as m3item  from
[dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item] A left outer join [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference] B 
on A.No_ = B.[Item No_] 
WHERE (A.No_ LIKE  '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI 
or A.Description LIKE '%020212601%' COLLATE  Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI 
or B.[Cross-Reference No_] LIKE  '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI)
```

I get:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+
|  itemno   | description | m3item |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| 020212601 | BLA BLA     |      0 |
| 020212601 | BLA BLA     |      0 |
| 020212601 | BLA BLA     |      0 |
| 020212601 | BLA BLA     |      0 |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

This means, my related table has 4 rows.

The next thing I do is add a filter in the WHERE clause, because I don't want some data in the second table:

```
select A.No_ as itemno,A.Description as description, A.[Producto M3] as m3item  from
[dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item] A left outer join [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference] B 
on A.No_ = B.[Item No_] 
WHERE (A.No_ LIKE  '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI 
or A.Description LIKE '%020212601%' COLLATE  Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI 
or B.[Cross-Reference No_] LIKE  '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI) 
and (B.[Cross-Reference Type] = 3)
```

This returns no rows at all! I was expecting to get one row, because I am using LEFT OUTER JOIN.

What I am missing? I need to get a row, even if there are no records in the second table

Comment: `and (B.[Cross-Reference Type] = 3)` is forcing your `left join` into an `inner join`, since B.[Cross-Reference Type] can also be NULL.

Comment: So is there any workaround to make it work like an outer join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the query you want is:

```
select A.No_ as itemno,A.Description as description, A.[Producto M3] as m3item 
from [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item] A left outer join
     [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference] B 
     on A.No_ = B.[Item No_] and
        B.[Cross-Reference Type] = 3
WHERE (A.No_ LIKE  '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI) or 
      (A.Description LIKE '%020212601%' COLLATE  Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI) or 
      (B.[Cross-Reference No_] LIKE  '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI) ;
```

You have a complicated condition on the second table.  The condition `= 3` needs to go into the `on` clause because it refers to all rows.  The other condition is optional as part of `or` conditions, so it can stay in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Indeed! as simple as moving the "=3" filter to the ON clause. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the restrictions on the second table in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join itself:

```
SELECT
    A.No_ AS itemno,
    A.Description AS description,
    A.[Producto M3] AS m3item
FROM [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item] A
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference] B
    ON A.No_ = B.[Item No_] AND
       B.[Cross-Reference No_] LIKE '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI
WHERE
    (A.No_ LIKE '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI OR
     A.Description LIKE '%020212601%' COLLATE  Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI) AND
    [Cross-Reference Type] = 3;
```

The problem with your current query is that the restrictions on the second table, appearing in the `WHERE` clause, may cause non matching records to prematurely be filtered off before the query completes.  The above suggestion should get around this problem.

Comment: It will still return no rows if [Cross-Reference Type] is NULL ?
What if he adds AND ([Cross-Reference Type] = 3 OR [Cross-Reference Type] IS NULL) ?

Comment: @WernerWaage No, not necessarily.  If I don't account for the `NULL` case, it might cause certain records in the result set to have `NULL` values for all `B` table columns, but this omission should not cause any records to be filtered off.

Comment: In my case, both options return no rows: moving restrictions to ON clause and also  "OR [Cross-Reference Type] IS NULL"

Answer (score 1):

It is a pity that your data samples don't provide all needed columns, and that you don't supply the DDL required. Notwithstanding, there are filtering predicates in your original query that reference the left joined table.

While you may have expected one row, I believe it is either 2 or 4 you would get by moving the predicates on alias B into the join.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PRUEBAS$Item(
>    No_      varchar(20)  NOT NULL
>   ,description VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL
>   ,[Producto M3]      VARCHAR(30)
> );
> INSERT INTO PRUEBAS$Item(No_,description) VALUES ('020212601','BLA BLA');
>
> CREATE TABLE [PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference](
>    Item_No_             varchar(20)  NOT NULL
>   ,CrossReference_Type  INTEGER  NOT NULL
>   ,CrossReference_No_   varchar(20) 
>   ,[Cross-Reference Type] INTEGER
>
> );
> INSERT INTO [PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference](Item_No_,CrossReference_Type,CrossReference_No_,[Cross-Reference Type]) VALUES ('020212601',2,NULL,3);
> INSERT INTO [PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference](Item_No_,CrossReference_Type,CrossReference_No_,[Cross-Reference Type]) VALUES ('020212601',2,'020212601',3);
> INSERT INTO [PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference](Item_No_,CrossReference_Type,CrossReference_No_,[Cross-Reference Type]) VALUES ('020212601',2,NULL,3);
> INSERT INTO [PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference](Item_No_,CrossReference_Type,CrossReference_No_,[Cross-Reference Type]) VALUES ('020212601',2,'020212601',3);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     A.No_           AS itemno
>   , A.Description   AS description
>   , A.[Producto M3] AS m3item
>   , b.*
> FROM [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item] A
> LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference] B ON A.No_ = B.[Item_No_]
>     AND B.[CrossReference_No_] LIKE '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI
>     AND (B.[Cross-Reference Type] = 3)
> WHERE (A.No_ LIKE '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI
>     OR A.Description LIKE '%020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI
>     )
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> itemno    | description | m3item | Item_No_  | CrossReference_Type | CrossReference_No_ | Cross-Reference Type
> :-------- | :---------- | :----- | :-------- | ------------------: | :----------------- | -------------------:
> 020212601 | BLA BLA     | null   | 020212601 |                   2 | 020212601          |                    3
> 020212601 | BLA BLA     | null   | 020212601 |                   2 | 020212601          |                    3
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     A.No_           AS itemno
>   , A.Description   AS description
>   , A.[Producto M3] AS m3item
>   , b.*
> FROM [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item] A
> LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PRUEBAS$Item Cross Reference] B ON A.No_ = B.[Item_No_]
>     AND (B.[Cross-Reference Type] = 3)
> WHERE (A.No_ LIKE '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI
>     OR A.Description LIKE '%020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI
>     OR B.[CrossReference_No_] LIKE '020212601%' COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CI_AI
>     )
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> itemno    | description | m3item | Item_No_  | CrossReference_Type | CrossReference_No_ | Cross-Reference Type
> :-------- | :---------- | :----- | :-------- | ------------------: | :----------------- | -------------------:
> 020212601 | BLA BLA     | null   | 020212601 |                   2 | null               |                    3
> 020212601 | BLA BLA     | null   | 020212601 |                   2 | 020212601          |                    3
> 020212601 | BLA BLA     | null   | 020212601 |                   2 | null               |                    3
> 020212601 | BLA BLA     | null   | 020212601 |                   2 | 020212601          |                    3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3fb2979dfa90956b3f1c9d55449e4ee8)*

not all column names agree exactly with your originals (spaces are a pain!)